# Llenar datatable con Elementos HTML

Tags: ajax, json, datatables

tengo un Datatable que estoy llenando mediante una llamada de AJAX a un Servicio. Todo funciona a la perfección, mi tabla se llena correctamente, aquí les comparto algo de script de AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: gContextPath + '/pacingSupervision/supervisionController/AJAXGetValuesToShow',
    data: {emailUser: username},
    success: function(result) {
        var jsonResult = JSON.parse(result);
            
        var listUsuarioLines = jsonResult[0]['listUsuarioLines'];   
        var listTasksLine = jsonResult[0]['listTasksLineRelations'];
        if( listTasksLine.length > 0 ){
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#datatableActivities').DataTable({
                    fixedHeader: true,
                    scrollX: true,
                    searching: true,
                    dom: 'Brtip',
                    buttons: [
                        'copyHtml5',
                        'excelHtml5',
                    ],
                    pageLength: 6,
                    data: listTasksLine,
                    columns: [
                        {"data" : "taskDescription"},
                        {"data" : "lineDescription"}
                        {"data" : "lineAcronym"}
                    ]
                 });
                    
            });
        }
            
    }, 
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
});
```

Mi datatable de ejemplo se muestra algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:
Tomando en cuenta esta forma de llenado:

```
data: listTasksLine,
columns: [
    {"data" : "taskDescription"},
    {"data" : "lineDescription"}
    {"data" : "lineAcronym"}
]
```

Existe alguna manera de que desde la configuración del datatable en la columna **Acción**, al momento de llenarla, se llene con elementos de HTML? en este caso, botones?

Quedando de esta Manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo alterno que he intentado, es directamente, del lado de mi servicio, armar el JSON, y definirle los objetos de HTML, (inputs, buttons, o cualquier elemento), y funciona, lo cual no sé es si sea algo correcto.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la respuesta, por si alguien la necesita:

```
columns: [
    {"data" : "taskDescription"},
    {"defaultContent" : ""},
    {"data" : "taskDescription",
           "render" : function ( data, type, row, meta ){
                            return "<input type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-success\" id=\"bttStartActivity\" name=\"bttStartActivity\" value=\"Iniciar Actividad\" onclick=\"startThisActivity('" + data + "')\" > " +
                                   "<input type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-secondary\" id=\"bttWatchActivity\" name=\"bttWatchActivity\" value=\"Ver Actividad\" disabled onclick=\"watchThisActivity('" + data + "')\"> ";
                      }
    }
```

**data**: Lo que hace es solo mostrar un dato del JSON de la Respuesta.

**defaultContent**: agrega la celda vacia.

**data**: le establecemos un valor, en este caso un valor de mi JSON de respuesta, y **render** transformará mediante la funcion establecida lo que tu quieras realizar.

En este caso, yo estoy regresando un Button, añadiendole una función al clickearlo lo cual mandará conforme a cada **Row** de la tabla, la actividad que depende.

Espero a alguien le sirva.